# make a body which moves continuously

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am working with **Box-2d** & **AndEngine**. I have dynamic body lets say a **Plane**. I want to moves this continuously with a given velocity. So, I set a linear Velocity to it. I have screen boundary(ground,roof,left & Right Wall) as well. Those are static body. When my plane collides with boundaries one or two times, it's becomes stopped. I apply no gravity to plane. Why plane stopped though it has fixed velocity? 
**Problem**: 
How I move the plane with continuous speed as well as corresponding direction after collide ? After that I want to move it where the user touches on the screen?

**Code**: create plane

```
FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory
                .createFixtureDef(1, .5f, 0.5f);

        aPlane = new Plane(222, 333, pilotTexures, vbom) {
            @Override
            protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            }
        };
        planeBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, aPlane,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(
                aPlane, planeBody, true, true));
        planeBody.setLinearVelocity(DEMO_VELOCITY_X, DEMO_VELOCITY_Y);
        attachChild(aPlane);
        planeBody.setGravityScale(0);
        planeBody.setUserData(PLANE);
```

**Code**: create boundary wall

```
final Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, camera_Height - 2,
        camera_Width, 2, vbom);
final Rectangle roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, camera_Width, 2, vbom);
final Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, camera_Height, vbom);
final Rectangle right = new Rectangle(camera_Width - 2, 0, 2,
        camera_Height, vbom);

final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,
        0.5f, 0.5f);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground,
        BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

Body roofBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof,
        BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
roofBody.setUserData(ROOF);

PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left,
        BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right,
        BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

attachChild(ground);
attachChild(roof);
attachChild(left);
attachChild(right);
```

I also create **ContactListener**, can listen when they collide . To move on finger touched point I also implements **IOnSceneTouchListener**

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try setting the elasticity of your walls to 1.0f and for regular contact remove the friction,

```
final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,
    0.5f, 0.0f);
```

To,

```
final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,
    1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Hop this helps.

Comment: Is the plane coming to a stop? Have you set the linear damping to 0? planeBody.setLinearDamping(0.0f);